# Is implementing an array class using ctypes more efficient than using lists?

Tags: python-3.x

Is implementing an array class using ctypes more efficient than using lists?
[Implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-dynamic-array-in-python/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ctypes are deterministic, you'll definitely meet some improvements.  But I think more than that, it highly depends on your application. What do you want to do with the List?
For example, if you are performing a simple search, then python's own functions and libraries will probably suffice (as they are written in C/C++).
For matrices and algebra-related types of work, you are better off using NumPy as it is highly efficient (comparable to C++ libraries such as Eigen).
Any other calculation-related work, implementing it with Ctype will definitely bring you some performance.